# Building with Cordova for BB9900

Tags: cordova, blackberry

I have been sitting with an issue for months now where I build for a BB9900 - the app tries to open and then immediately closes.. Is this a known issue for BB9900?

I see the platform is not supported anymore?

Any suggestions are welcome.

CORDOVA INFORMATION

Node version: v0.12.7

Cordova version: 5.1.1

Config.xml file:

```
<widget id="IntegriSure" version="0.0.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
  xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>IntegriSure</name>
  <description>A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.</description>
  <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">Apache Cordova Team</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <access origin="http://azurewebsites.net" subdomains="false"/>
  <access origin="https://azurewebsites.net" subdomains="false"/>
  <access origin="http://integrisureapp.azurewebsites.net" subdomains="false"/>
  <preference name="WebSecurity" value="enable"/>
</widget>
```

Plugins:

com.blackberry.ui.toast,hu.dpal.phonegap.plugins.SpinnerDialog,it.mobimentum.phonegapspinnerplugin,nl.x-services.plugins.toast,org.apache.cordova.camera,org.apache.cordova.device,org.apache.cordova.dialogs,org.apache.cordova.file,org.apache.cordova.geolocation,org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser,org.apache.cordova.media,org.apache.cordova.media-capture,org.apache.cordova.vibration

Comment: Please add more information about cordova version you're using and about your code.

Comment: @lifeisfoo added above

Answer (score 0):

Searching in the Cordova documentation seems that the latest version that (partially, without CLI) supports blackberry < 10 [is the 3.2.0](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.2.0/guide_support_index.md.html#Platform%20Support). Look at [this](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.2.0/guide_platforms_index.md.html#blackberry) for the guides related to the your platform.

Latest version of Cordova (3.3+) [removed](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide_support_index.md.html#Platform%20Support) the old blackberry platform from the supported list.

Comment: I see - I will do some reading and comment back. Thanks very much